# Unable to read Resource Section : ResHacker

Tags: batch-file, icons

i want to change a Icon with a ResHacker-Batch File.

I use following Batch-Script :

```
ResHacker.exe -script resscript.txt
ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache
pause
```

And i use following Ressource-Hacker Script

```
[FILENAMES]

Exe=Q:\ResHack\VM_Projekt_64.exe

SaveAs= Q:\ResHack\VM_Projekt_64.exe

Log= VMLOG.log

[COMMANDS]

-addoverwrite  Q:\ResHack\icon.ico, ICONGROUP,MAINICON,0


//This script replaces the icon
```

But when i start the script i get following Message in my Logfile : "Error: Unable to read Resource Section."

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Top-5 result when googling for the error text: [Why my Resource Hacker doesn't work with some .EXE files](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/2060)

Comment: i read all of these . But i find the mistake by my self. My Reshacker was not able to convert 64-Bit Programs.

Comment: @P4T, so if you found the solution consider to post it as an answer and accept it, so the question does no longer appear open...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i needed a 64 bit Version of Resource Hacker